# Como fazer update de um campo já existente no banco de dados? Laravel

Tags: laravel

Preciso fazer a atualização de um campo sem alterar a descrição, segue a imagem abaixo.

[image: Imagem print tela]

Mudei o campo de TIPO DE SERVIÇO mas tenho que manter a mesma descrição, como faço isso?
OBS: Estou em um estágio dai me pediram pra resolver esse problema, ainda sou um pouco leigo.

Segue o código update do controller:

```
 public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $item = Service::findOrFail($id);

    Validator::make(
        $request->all(),
        $this->rules($request, $item->getKey())
    )->validate();

    $item->fill($request->all());

    if ($request->hasFile('image') && $request->file('image')->isValid()) {

        $upload = $request->image->store('services', 'public');

        if ($item->icon) {
            Storage::disk('public')->delete($item->icon);
        }

        $item->icon = $upload;
    }
    $item->save();


    return redirect()->route('services.index')
        ->withStatus('Registro atualizado com sucesso.');
}
```

E a parte de validação:

```
private function rules(Request $request, $primaryKey = null, bool $changeMessages = false)
{
    $rules = [
        'description' => ['required', 'max:40', 'unique:services,description'],
        'is_enabled' => ['required'],
        'type_id' => ['required'],
        'image' => 'nullable|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:1024',
    ];

    $messages = [
        'description.unique' => 'Descrição já existe!',
    ];

    return !$changeMessages ? $rules : $messages;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Já resolvir, era só usar o RULE ficando o código assim:

```
Rule::unique('services')->ignore($primaryKey)
```